# jquery to populate div with image and populate input

Tags: jquery, image, html, populate

I have the following jquery syntax that populates an input in my table row with a value:

```
row.find('input[name^="bandstatus"]').val('InRange');
```

In each row, I have a unique div named priceflag in which I want to show a green flag image or red flag. so 1st row is `priceflag1`, 2nd row is `priceflag2`, 3rd row is `priceflag3` etc...

normally I would populate a div with $('#results').html(data); but how do I populate the corresponding table row div with an image.

something like:

```
$('name^="priceflag).val(\images\redflag.png)
```

Hope this question makes sense.

Thanks a million as always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[name^="priceflag"]').html('<img src="/images/redflag.png" />')
```

Note you have to be aware of using back slashes like you are doing. In javascript, the sequence "\r" is actually a carriage return when it appears inside a string.  All modern operating systems recognize forward slashes in paths.

Comment: Thanks. This produces error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: name^="priceflag"` any ideas? Thanks,

Comment: @Smudger, Are you forgetting the brackets?  Copying and pasting the code I posted into a test event handler works fine for me. (jquery 1.9.1)

Comment: Yeah, I get your error when I delete the brackets.  Add brackets.

Comment: Also, note that val() is used on form input elements.  A <div> is not a form input element.  The jQuery html() function is like the javascript innerHTML() function, which has a more descriptive name. With jQuery's html() function, first you obtain the tag you want using a selector, then html() erases everything between the tag and replaces it with whatever you specify, i.e. html tags or plain text.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to put an image in the tabe row div:

```
$('div[id^="priceflag"]').html("<img src='\images\redflag.png' />");
```

Comment: @Smudger appology for late reply, but problem was div has an `id` not `name` that's why nothing is happening. Just updated the answer you can try this one now.

Comment: @Smudger how is that come?

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend using a ViewModel in this case, take Knockout.js for example. With that you can automatically assign classes, trigger functions etc. without manually fiddling with finding the right element to change. (Take a look: http://knockoutjs.com/)